# How to update the value of Total of functional every change of dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

here is my main table where i want to get the sum of total "functional", "repair", "condemn", "stole" of the item that is currently displayed.

my problem is that even I apply filter it still return the sum of all even it is not displayed on my table.

```
<p><span>Functional: <span id="functional"></span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Repair: <span id="repair"></span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <table id="emp-table">
        <thead>
            <th col-index = 1>ID</th>
            <th col-index = 2>BATCH
                <select class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows(), asd()">
                    <option value="all">ALL</option>
                </select>
            </th>

            <th col-index = 3>DISTRICT
                <select class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows(), asd()">
                    <option value="all">ALL</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th  col-index = 4>SCHOOL
                <select class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows(), asd()">
                    <option value="all">ALL</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <th  col-index = 5>FUNCTIONAL
             <!--    <select class="table-filter" onchange="filter_rows()">
                    <option value="all">ALL</option>
                </select> -->
            </th>
                   <th col-index = 6>REPAIR
                        </th>
                 <th >TOTAL</th>
            
        </thead>

                    <?php
                        if($query_run)
                        {

                               
                            foreach($query_run as $row)
                            {

                    ?>  
        <tbody>
            <tr class="inputItem">
                                 
                                <td > <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>    
                                 <td> <?php echo $row['pck_no']; ?> </td>
                                   <td> <?php echo $row['district']; ?> </td>   
                                     <td> <?php echo $row['school_name']; ?> </td>
                                     <td class="sample"> <?php echo $row['functional']; ?> </td>
                                     <td class="sample1"> <?php echo $row['repair']; ?> </td>  
                                       <td id=TotMarks></td>
</tr>   

        </tbody>
                  <?php       
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "No Record Found";

                        }
                        ?>
    </table>


  <span id="val"></span>



</div>
</div>
```

Here is my script it happens in every dropdown not changing the values

```
    <script>
        
        function asd(){
        var table = document.getElementById("emp-table"), sumVal = 0, sumrepair = 0;

        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
        {
            sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML);
             sumrepair = sumrepair + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[5].innerHTML);


        }
I want to the value of functional changes of sum if the dropdown is changes. 
             # This is the display of total of functional
             document.getElementById("functional").innerHTML = sumVal; 
             document.getElementById("repair").innerHTML = sumrepair; 
            
        }

    </script>
```

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilVfx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check how your filter works. It should remove rows from DOM, otherwise if it just hides them visually (probably with CSS), then your javascript will always count all rows (what happens right now, I assume).